# Unexpected afterAll execution in Jest/Testing Library test suite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing some asynchronous behavior in a React component, including loading and error states. I'm approaching the different states through the use of different `describe` blocks that set up the states, like so:

```js
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch');

describe('The App', () => {
  const promiseWithDelay = (json, delay=0) =>
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(
        () => resolve({
          ok: true,
          json: () => json
        }), delay
      )
    );

  describe('given data loading', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      global.fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        promiseWithDelay(someData, 50)
      );

      await waitFor(() => render(<App />));
    });

    // ... successful tests for a loading state here
  });

  describe('some other tests', () => {
    // ... more setup and other tests here
  });
});
```

I'm creating a loading state by mocking `fetch`

The tests all pass, but I get the `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` error, which I assumed to be because the `render` from the first describe block doesn't totally resolve before the tests in the second `describe` block start running.

To clear the error, I originally thought to include an `afterAll` function in the first `describe` block to wait for the `Promise` that creates the loading state to resolve, like so:

```js
describe('The App', () => {
  // ... etc

  describe('given data loading', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      // ... etc
    });

    // ... successful tests for a loading state here

    afterAll(async () => {
      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.queryByTestId('some-rendered-content')).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
    });
  });

  describe('some other tests', () => {
    // ... more setup and other tests here
  });
});
```

This didn't clear the error, but changing the `afterAll` function to an `afterEach` function did the trick.

Totally perplexed, I added some console logging to see what was happening when, and discovered this:

```sh
// afterEach console logs

beforeEach: Starting loading test
test: Testing loading
afterEach: Cleaning up from loading test
afterEach: Waiting for content to render
afterEach: Waiting for content to render
afterEach: Cleaned up from loading test
some other test: Starting next test
```

```sh
// afterAll console logs

beforeEach: Starting loading test
test: Testing loading
afterAll: Cleaning up from loading test
afterAll: Waiting for content to render
(console.error): Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. (etc.)
afterAll: Waiting for content to render
afterAll: Waiting for content to render
... afterAll: Waiting for content to render logs many times here
some other test: Starting next test
```

Can anyone explain the order of operations here and what might be causing the warning with `afterAll` but not `afterEach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning means that tested component has asynchronous side effects (represented by `fetch` in this test suite) that weren't waited by some tests.

`afterAll` is applied to a group of tests inside respective `describe`, if there are multiple tests, some of them won't be affected by a delay that `waitFor` in `afterAll` provides.

As it can be expected from the integration with test framework, React Testing Library does a cleanup in order for tests to not affect each other, and `afterEach` is the right place for this. As [the documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#skipping-auto-cleanup)  states,

> Cleanup is called after each test automatically by default if the testing framework you're using supports the afterEach global (like mocha, Jest, and Jasmine).

A correct way to write tests is is to wait for side effects inside the component to be completed before RTL cleanup. This requires to wait in each test at least for the same amount of time as the duration of side effect (50ms), and a bit more in order for a promise to be flushed. The use of `waitFor` allows to no rely on implementation details. Since side effects can affect test results, a correct place for `waitFor` is `beforeEach` or a test itself, not `afterEach` or `afterAll`.

Also `await waitFor(() => render(<App />))` serves no good purpose as it's effective only for functions that throw errors, most commonly assertions. It can be reduced to `render(<App />)`.

Comment: Thats a very good answer! I would add that there is probably no reason to add a delay to the promise--you could simply use `global.fetch.mockResolvedValue({ ok: true });`. If you really want to keep the `setTimeout` around, you can look into `jest.useFakeTimers();` to prevent slowing down your tests.

Comment: I appreciate the really thorough information! It helped me understand the behavior of `afterAll` and `afterEach` better. As far as `await waitFor(() => render(<App />))` is concerned, that's only there to prevent an `act(...)` warning the test throws otherwise.

Comment: @Doug I'm using `setTimeout` to simulate a delay in resolving a promise to test the loading state. This is less to elapse time for the sake of elapsing time as it is to catch the loading state before the mock Promise resolves.

Comment: @EstusFlask `await act(() => render(<App />))` throws several warnings `The callback passed to act(...) function must return undefined, or a Promise.`, `An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).` and `Do not await the result of calling act(...) with sync logic, it is not a Promise.` `waitFor` throws none of those warnings.